# Copying/pasting feature geometry only

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Does anyone know of a way in QGIS to copy a single feature in a layer and to paste it back into the same layer WITHOUT copying over the attributes?

Comment: So you only want to copy the geometry with an empty attribute table?

Comment: If these features haven't the same attributes in layer structure that QGIS will copy objects with empty attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your features in an intermediate table which have no fields . Then you copy this result to your destination table. You will have geometry but no attributes.

Comment: This does work. Using a temporary scratch layer as the intermediate step.  Simple and effective. Thanks