# QGIS copy and move features without attribute

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector-layer, copy

I use the **Advanced digitizing toolbar -> Copy and move features** tool quote often. The biggest problem I have got is that the content from the data attribute table is also replicated.
[image]

Is there any way to make the "copy and move features" by keeping the attribute table content blank for the duplicated feature?

I think a similar issue was raised here:

[Copy a geometry from one feature to another without attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20942/copy-a-geometry-from-one-feature-to-another-without-attributes)

but it applies rather for the separate layers.

Comment: There are other questions discussing this, in addition to the one you mention. I'm not sure about the [plugin mentioned here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333516/110158) but almost all answers do this through an intermediate scratch layer, probably because of the potential annoyance of having two features with exactly the same geometry in one layer. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184057/copying-pasting-feature-geometry-only. The final destination for the feature could be the original layer or a different one.

Comment: OK, the question under your link doesn't solve the problem as I don't know what is the "intermediate table". Could you clarify?

Comment: You are correct, my comment does not answer how to do this in one layer. Instead, I added another link to answers doing this into separate layers and a rationale for why the software might not be designed to copy geometries in place in the same layer. If that was easy to do, I think users would end up with a lot of layers with unintended, somewhat invisible, duplicate features. As one example of creating an intermediate layer, create a new temporary scratch layer.

Comment: I think it won't be the perfect solution, as it adds up quite a lot of additional work

Comment: i wonder if there is a 'clear all attribute values' tool/plugin which would help here. Copy-paste, then clear attributes. Maybe investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is instead to Move and Copy feature using the "Add new point/line/polygon feature" and therefore we will get all the columns from the attribute value with empty inputs. We need just use the one criterion on which our styling was based and that's it!

[image]